# Can't connect to the internet with an ethernet cable in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: internet, 20.10, lan, wired

My PC has an MSI motherboard and Intel i9 10th gen processor. I installed Ubuntu 20.10 on my new PC and I can't connect to the internet with the Ethernet cable.

I don't even see the wired section in the settings. I searched here and I tried to go to `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change the `manage=false` to `manage=true` and it didn't work. I also tried `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`. I tried to reset the internet and it is also didn't work. All packages are is up to date. I can say that the internet connection is fine because it's working fine on my laptop and I also see the green light from the motherboard when I connect the LAN cable. The WiFi is also working fine.

Results of `sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b33 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d2
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b8 (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06be (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0685
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 3241
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983``
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `sudo lspci` as well as the brand and model of your computer? This will make it much easier for someone to provide some specific information that might help you solve your problem 

Comment: RTL8125 is still not supported. What you did only made things worse.

Comment: Maybe this some of this is working.  https://github.com/awesometic/realtek-r8125-dkms `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2`